# What is this plant with distinctive leaves?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Location: Vienna, Austria

Leaf size: two big thumbnails

Plant height: large thumb
[image]

I assumed it might have come from the seeds of some fruit I ate.  I consulted these websites:

https://www.baumkunde.de/baumbestimmung/

http://www.blattbestimmung.de/blattform-herzfoermig

but found nothing. Perhaps it is neither shrub nor tree.

Edit: 
This is how it looks now, ten days later:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seedlings are often tricky to determine, but I think this may be the common weed [*Chenopodium album*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chenopodium_album) (from the family Amaranthaceae). This is common across Europe, and the leaf shape, growth pattern and the silverly underside seen on the top leaf in your picture fits well.

Here are pictures of a seeding and a larger plant:

[image]
(from [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/99758165@N06/18216589254/))

[image]
(from https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu)

Comment: I totally agree on Chenopodium, however, members of this group are extremly hard to distuingish, so maybe you should just settle with the family?

Comment: @blabbath Where you write "*settle with the family*", are you referring to the actual family (Amaranthaceae) or the genus (Chenopodium). In general, I agree though, which is also why I phased it as "may be". It could well be another species in the genus, even though *C. album* is most common in many parts of Europe.

Comment: The genus of course, my fault. But I can live with your answer as it is =)